# Use pip module from Python to install modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

My goal is to use the `pip` module, from Python 3.6 code, to install a new Python module. I can't seem to figure out the correct steps to call instantiate and invoke a `pip.commands.InstallCommand()` instance, however.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import pip
inst = pip.commands.InstallCommand()
inst.name = 'boto3'
inst.run()
```

I'm not even sure if this is the correct method of invoking the `InstallCommand` class. The error I'm getting, when running the above code, is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   TypeError: run() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'options' and 'args'

I'm not sure what to pass in for `options` and `args` though.

**Question**: Does anyone know what the correct invocation of the pip `InstallCommand` looks like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only supported way to `pip install` from a script is via a subprocess.  See the section in the documentation [*Using pip from your program*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program):

> `pip` is a command line program. While it is implemented in Python, and so is available from your Python code via `import pip`, you must not use pip’s internal APIs in this way. ... The most reliable approach, and the one that is fully supported, is to run pip in a subprocess. This is easily done using the standard subprocess module.

Use `sys.executable` to ensure you're targeting the correct pip for the current runtime:

```
import subprocess, sys
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'boto3'])
```

Comment: Interesting, so what's the point of the `InstallCommand` class?

Comment: Lower level interfaces.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I was hoping for an interface with logical, named parameters, but I'll take your word for it. eg. `pip.commands.InstallCommand().run(name='pynapple')`

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for checking it out. Use of named parameters would be convenient and easier to understand, but if it doesn't exist, it doesn't exist.

Comment: As of pip v19.3.1, `pip.main` no longer exists...  You can use import `pip.__main__; pip.__main__._main()` but I'm not sure that's recommended.

Comment: @florisla Yes, pip moved all internal APIs so me time ago to discourage this usage. Updated the answer.

Comment: @DustinIngram Out of curiosity, what's going on with the slug anchors? #id9 probably won't be stable if sections are added above in future.

Comment: @wim No idea, just noticed the original no longer existed. :/

Answer (score -5):

According to with https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

You can install any package by using at a command prompt:
pip install 'SomeProject'

Comment: The OP wants to install a module using Python code, not from command prompt